# PHP: Converting Unicode strings to ANSI strings

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8

<s>Does PHP have any standard function(s) to convert Unicode strings to plain, good old-fashioned ANSI strings (or whatever format PHP's `htmlentities` understands?</s>

Is there any function that converts UTF-8 strings to HTML that can be understood by the most popular browsers?

Comment: "ANSI strings"? http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: It isn't like my software will be used by some random guy in Japan. We know our market.

Comment: Why not just keep everything (web page, database tables, connection and collation, etc.) in UTF-8? Even if you don't take advantage of any non-ASCII characters you'd at least have a consistent approach.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase my function.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could downvote my own questions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can't work properly. Stored with Unicode there are many more Characters than with ANSI.
So if you "convert" to ANSI, you will loose lots of charackters.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

You can use Unicode (UTF-8) charset with htmlentities:

`string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT [, string $charset [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )`

`htmlentities($myString, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");` should work.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that was possible. I thought `htmlentities` only accepted one parameter.

Comment: Is there any function that converts `á` to `&aacute`, for example?

Answer (score 7):

Whilst I'd *really* recommend keeping everything in UTF-8 (as per my comment on the question), you can use the [mb_convert_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function to convert any known UTF-8 string to US-ASCII as such:

```
$asciiString = mb_convert_encoding ($sourceString, 'US-ASCII', 'UTF-8');
```

However, this may not be a lossless conversion depending on the source character string. (Characters such as "é" will simply disappear into the void.)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers already understand UTF-8. If you want them to *know* that you're sending them UTF-8 then you need to [*tell them*](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset).

Comment: Does IE6 understand UTF-8? Some of the viewers of my Web site might be using it.

Comment: Yes, it does.  However, it doesn't auto-detect UTF-8, so make sure to declare the `Content-Type` appropriately.