# How to replace UTF-8 characters with similar-looking ASCII characters with PHP?

Tags: php, utf8-decode

I have a problem about Unicode. I need a function in PHP to convert the string:

> Xin chào tất cả các bạn. Mình không biết tiếng anh.

To:

> Xin chao tat ca cac ban. Minh khong biet tieng anh.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4691477/418413)

Comment: The title doesn't match with the question, the text encoding is the same in the 2 strings (Stack Overflow uses UTF-8). Your question is more about transforming the text by removing the non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`iconv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with the `//TRANSLIT` modifier:

```
$str1 = "Xin chào tất cả các bạn. Mình không biết tiếng anh.";
$str2 = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $str1);
print($str1.PHP_EOL.$str2);
```

The output will be:

> `Xin chào tất cả các bạn. Mình không biết tiếng anh.`
>   `Xin chao tat ca cac ban. Minh khong biet tieng anh.`

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/138693)

Comment: Thanks. 
But Code not support all version PHP5 and error on XAMP with version PHP5.5 "Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in". Please help and check on phpversion higher.
Demo: [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f37911751133eff5dc30e0660d31029ced0e7d2)

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the PHP version. It has been caused by the locale of the server. Use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.UTF-8");` to get rid of your problem. [**DEMO**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f32dc661340114cd4b819c5149196dc6c5f2852f)

Comment: Thanks very much! Code error with PHP5.5.9 :(
[link](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-aUPXWUu0iUA/U1SVMUE5wHI/AAAAAAAAJ3Q/poNF3Af61ZY/s1024/upanh.vndailys.com-Capture.JPG)